# The difference between prompt to build and always build

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a project developed with asp.net web form.
Recently, our team encountered a new problem, and that is that if a change is made in the core layers of the project, the build time of the project takes almost 10 minutes.
For example, if in the **core layer**, the code `string a = "sad"`; , the project build time **will increase**.
When I set the option to Prompt to build from the path **Debug-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Build And Run-->On Run , when Projects are out of date**, the time to build the project is reduced but not al lot.
I wanted to know what is the difference between **Prompt to build** and **Always build**? And how does this change affect my project?

Note: In Debug--> Debug Properties --> Build , I set "Before running startup page" to Build Page , then problem solved and project build in a second!
really I do not know what happen ! and What do these changes do and does it affect the project build process and change files and apply them or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Prompt to build**: When you have "Prompt to build" selected, Visual Studio will ask you whether to build the project before running it. If you choose to build, Visual Studio will check if any changes have been made to the project since the last build, and if so, it will perform a build before running the project. This option allows you to control when the build process occurs, and you can choose to skip the build if you believe it is not necessary.
2. **Always build**: With "Always build" selected, Visual Studio will automatically perform a build before running the project, regardless of whether any changes have been made. This option ensures that the project is built every time you run it, regardless of the state of the project files. It can be useful when you want to ensure that the latest code changes are always reflected in the executed application.

The choice between "Prompt to build" and "Always build" depends on your workflow and preferences. If you frequently make changes to your project and want to ensure that the most up-to-date version is always built and run, selecting "Always build" can save you the extra step of manually triggering a build. On the other hand, if you prefer more control over when the build process occurs, or if you only want to build when you think it is necessary, "Prompt to build" allows you to make that decision on a case-by-case basis.

Build Page : When you write wrong code and you are on prompt to build, for example int a ="1"; , an error does not occur during build (compile error does not occurs) and an error occurs during execution(RunTime error occurs).

If you select build page with always build , the problem solved , but still I can not understand what is different between build website and build page